# Python iso calendar 1st Jan

Tags: python, date

I'm using this function to compute the week number from a date ( it counts the weeks starting from 0 ):

```
 time.strftime("%U", datetime(2017,1,1).timetuple())
```

it is returning 1. If you try another year, I.e:

```
 time.strftime("%U", datetime(2018,1,1).timetuple())
```

it return 0. Fine, it is the 1st week for 2018 year.

It is crystal clear that the 2017 begins with Sunday and this day actually belongs to the week before: December 26, 2016    January 1, 2017

But the last week of 2016 is number 52, so why the function is returning 1 instead 51?

Comment: `time.strftime` expects a `struct_time`, not a `datetime`. Do you mean `datetime(...).strftime('%U')`?

Comment: datetime(....).timetuple() Sorry, I edited the question ... too many days struggling with this issue. Of course I can add an IF to solve the problem but want to understand the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: `%U` — *Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. __All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.__* — Works exactly as advertised.

Comment: ok, All days in a new year preceding the *first* Sunday are considered to be in week 0. But there are not days before the 1st Jan in 2017. If Sundays is the week-separator why is taken in count?

Comment: 1-1-2017 *is* the first Sunday of the year, whereas the first Sunday of 2018 is the 7th, hence 2018 has some days before the first Sunday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213419/discussion-between-ozw1z5rd-and-deceze).

Comment: You don't have to *like* the definition, it simply is what it is. There's gotta be *some* definition of a "week", and as soon as you try to define it you run into a number of edge case issues. These have been solved here with a "week 0" and "week 53". If you'd come up with your own definition you'd need to solve the same kind of problems somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%U` can return a value ranging from 0 to 53, where each week is defined as starting on a Sunday The values 1 though 52 make sense, as you typically think of a year as containing 52 weeks. So let's look at the situations where a day occurs in week 0 or week 53.

January 1, 2017 was on a Sunday, so as expected, it occurs during Week 1:

```
>>> datetime(2017, 1, 1).strftime("%U")
'01'
```

December 24, 2017 is the Sunday that starts Week 52

```
>>> datetime(2017, 12, 24).strftime("%U")
'52'
```

But what, then, to make of December 31? Clearly, there is slightly *more* than 52 weeks in a year (since 7 * 52 == 364), so we treat the week that "mostly" bleeds into the following year as Week 53.

```
>>> datetime(2017, 12, 31).strftime("%U")
'53'
```

This week coincides with the week 0 from the perspective of 2018:

```
>>> datetime(2018, 1, 1).strftime("%U")
'00'
```

since the first Sunday of 2018 is January 7:

```
>>> datetime(2018, 1, 7).strftime("%U")
'01'
```

So Week 53 of 2017 and Week 00 of 2018 refer to the same same span of days, December 31, 2017 through January 6, 2018. We just use different *numbers* to refer to it, depending on whether we are asking about it as a week containing a day from 2017 or as a week continuing days from 2018.

This also implies that some years (like 2017) don't have a Week 0, and other years (like 2016) do not have a Week 53.

```
>>> datetime(2016, 12, 31).strftime("%U")
'52'
```

No year has both Week 0 *and* Week 53. But in all years, Weeks 1 through 52 consist of 7 days in the given year. Further, if a year has a Week 53, the following year will have a Week 0.

And as a final bit of trivia, Week 53 will *usually* start on December 31. The occasional exception is a leap year that begins on a Sunday, where Week 53 starts on December 30. The last one was 2012; the next such year is 2040.

Comment: 0 to 53 that is 54 possibile values. 0-52?

Comment: No year has both Week 0 and Week 53. I've added a note to clarify that.